# Install ubuntu on Dell inspiron 2 in1

Tags: uninstall, inspiron

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000  2-IN-1. The install hangs about 5 lines into the on-screen progress.

Is it possible to do this ? If so, some tips would be appreciated. Would a different release be better ?
I dont care if the touch screen works.
Thanks
Curt

Comment: Thanks, when dvd tries to boot, I get: request failed for pin 180, kernel panic - not syncing Timeout: not all cups entered broadcast exception handler....I have disabled secure boot, set ahci, and verified the ubuntu download...

Answer (score 1):

CW,the great majority of DELL notebooks are compatible with Ubuntu. I use a Dell Inspiron 7472 with 19.10 without any issues.
You did not gave much information about how you are doing the installation, so I will assume somethings.
You probably have created a live USB stick from the ISO image downloaded from Ubuntu website, in Windows 10. depending on the software you used to burn and quality of your internet access, sometimes the ISO image gets corrupted and can cause the symptoms you described.
What you should do.

- Burn the iso again with a different software, for windows you can use "Etcher" (https://www.balena.io/etcher/).
- re-download the image from canonical and verify the checksum of the file. and the burn the ISO.

Things you can check also are BIOS configurations, UEFI partition, graphics card. You also can check Dell's web site (https://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brdhs1/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) they have a hole page explaining how to install Linux on their computers.

Lipe