# Can't enter GRUB after Ubuntu 19.10 installation on Dell Inspiron 15 2-in-1

Tags: dual-boot, dell, inspiron

A few days ago I got a new Dell Inspiron 15 2-in-1 with Windows 10 and have been trying to install Ubuntu (initially 18.04) on it. Initially, I was having the exact same problem described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192600/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-2-in1).

However, I read [this post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1047416/linux/nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-18-10-/post/5398402/#5398402) that say that the CPU (Intel Core i5-10210U) is probably too new for the (Ubuntu 18.04) Kernel version and so I moved to try with 19.10 (Kernel version >=5.3). This didn't work just like that.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1851901), someone had installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a similar PC after a BIOS update, which I was able to do following [Dell's website instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln129956/dell-bios-updates?lang=en) but first disabling BitLocker.

After all this I could finally boot Ubuntu 19.10 from the USB stick and go through the installation process. During installation, in the Installation Type window I choose *Something Else* and created the primary and swap partitions for Ubuntu as I usually do and the installation went smooth.

However, after rebooting I don't see the GRUB. I can see Ubuntu is installed but I can't enter. Also, when I enter the BIOS One-Time Boot Settings I can see Ubuntu on the UEFI Boot Devices, but when I choose it I am taken to a Dell screen Pre-Boot System Performance Check that says *No bootable devices found*.
This is how my disk looks like right now :

[image: My disk partition]

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media, is how it installs. Ubuntu now uses swap file, so swap partition not required, but will be used. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred, thank you for your reply. I did install in UEFI mode since this PC does not seem to support legacy mode. I went into the live installer and tried the Boot-repair but it seems that some dependencies are broken. This is what happens when I try to add the repository and install Boot-repair

Comment: E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4h 18min 35s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

Comment: I made sure my 18.04 system was up to date `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` then ran commands to add repository, update & run Boot-Repair. A couple of minor warning issues on theme parsing, but it ran ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I finally have a functional installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Dell Inspiron 15 7000 2-in-1 with Wi-Fi and touch screen drivers working.

After the BIOS update that I described above, I realized that I could install not only Ubuntu 19.10 but also Ubuntu 18.04 which I prefer for being a LTS. However, after a successful installation I could not dual boot(could not see the GRUB). I'm not 100% sure what the problem was, but it seems that in my previous attempts of installing Ubuntu something went wrong and the partitions were all over the place. I reinstalled Windows 10 using the original Dell recovery partition (backing up all data first) and tried installing Ubuntu again and this time it worked perfectly.

The only problem after this was that Ubuntu did not recognize Wi-Fi controller. I used a wired mobile shared-connection and updated the Linux Kernel version to v5.3.1 using the instructions [here](https://vitux.com/update-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-through-ukuu/). It works perfectly so far.